# How to recover personal data on an Android phone which is in a bootloop?

Tags: data-recovery, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-note-4

Is there a way to recover the internal storage (images, video, photos, notes, app data, music, etc) of an Android phone which is *currently* **in a bootloop**?

Additional info:

1. Wiping the cache partition in recovery mode does not solve the bootloop issue.
2. The phone is not rooted.
3. USB debugging (hopefully) has been enabled prior to the soft-bricking.
4. The bootloop occurred after the battery run out of power.
5. The phone is SAMSUNG Galaxy Note 4

Comment: Bootloader unlocked? Can you boot to a custom recovery e.g. TWRP? Encryption enabled on device? If yes, can TWRP decrypt it?

Comment: How do you check if the bootloader has been unlocked? I haven't installed any custom recovery. I can only get access to the normal/regular/stock recovery. Is there a way to install TWRP through there without wiping out my files?

Comment: See some rooting guide for your device to get answers to all of your queries. In short, it seems you haven't unlocked bootloader, which if you do now, will wipe everything. With locked bootloader you can't recover data.

Comment: pretty dire sounding... Do you think there is any way to recover at least some well known file formats like images, S-note files, audio files, etc.?

Comment: You mentioned usb-debugging check if adb detect your device during boot/loop. another option: cf-auto-root seems to support your device which means you can inject recovery with locked bootloader. not sure about details check your model is not verizon first https://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4/help/sm-n910-cf-auto-root-t2897428

Comment: As our [boot-loop tag wiki](/tags/boot-loop/info) suggests: have you tried booting into safe-mode? You might be lucky enough to use ADB while in there.

Comment: try to install PhilZ Touch Recovery CWM 6 from stock Android system recovery <3e> (apply update from sdcard) trlte/xx
https://mega.co.nz/#F!oZ1QDDbC!Ko20UNhowwIlXLVFjJsyKw

Comment: check for cloud backups https://photos.google.com or https://drive.google.com/drive/backups

Comment: I will try both of your sugestions, alecxs. Thank you.